# Prezi.com: how to prevent zooming by clicking on swf-object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, prezi

I need to use an interactive flash clip with Prezi, but mouse event in this clip makes prezi to zoom-in. I want my clip to prevent reaction of prezi-stage. There were a good solution for this: http://tjoadesign.nl/blog/?p=303 but now it's not work anymore and i have no ideas why... Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Hide built in context menu items

[Adobe documentation on ContextMenuBuiltInItems](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuBuiltInItems.html)